# Calling Static method in multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

Consider this code:

```
public class Test
{
        public void Print()
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Console.WriteLine("Print");
            }
        }
        public static void Somthing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Somthing");
        }
}
```

In `print` method I `lock` the class and `Somthing` is a static method. I expect when calling `Somthing` after ther `Print`,`Somthing` run  Separately Thread,because I don't have instance of `Test` for calling `Somthing`.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var test = new Test();
     test.Print();
     Test.Somthing();
}
```

But when write above code ,`Test` locked and then call `Somthing`.

Why compiler has this behavior?

Comment: I believe that `lock(this)` locks the *current instance*, and static methods are not tied to any particular instance but the class type itself, hence the evil confusion. I'll let someone better informed formulate a coherent answer though, 'cause I might very well be wrong... :)

Comment: Locking in itself doesn't create a separate thread, it just locks access so that only one thread can get inside at a time. Locking also doesn't really do anything if everything is called inside a single thread like your code does.

Comment: 1 only see one thread in your example code ?

Comment: What is the problem here? Why would you expect the static method to run on a separate thread? You're calling it from the same thread. The lock effectively does nothing here.

Comment: [MSDN for lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) suggests you avoid locking `this` for publically accessible types.

Comment: "I expect when calling Somthing after ther Print,Somthing run Separately Thread". Why do you expect that?

Comment: This got nothing to do with threads, there is one single thread. -1 because you didn't try to learn about threads, not even the basics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing in here that would cause another thread to be used; why would it? your code:

- creates an instance of `Test`
- invokes (`callvirt`) `Print` on that instance

  - which takes a `Monitor` lock around itself (not a good idea, btw)
  - sleeps for 10 seconds
  - writes a line to the console
  - releases the `Monitor` lock
- invokes (`call`) the static `Something` method

  - which writes a line to the console

No extra threads required. I should emphasize: it would work identically with regards to threads even if you *didn't* release the `Monitor` lock (by using `Monitor.Enter` without a `Monitor.Exit`); again: `lock` *does not create threads*.

A `lock` simply stops (blocks) ***other*** threads from `lock`ing the same object for the duration - it creates a mutually exclusive region. It doesn't create threads.

Answer (score 3):

`lock` just avoids another thread from accessing the code inside the block to access until the handle is returned. In you case, you actually have a single thread (outside lock). The code inside the lock statement doesn't get locked by anything. Code gets executed synchronously meaning - Thread sleeps for the specified time and then calls `Something` method.